# How to stop the scrolling and the web toolbar from appearing?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp-classic

I have implemented this piece of code in my application.
How do I change it to prevent it from scrolling and the URL from appearing in the browser?

```
function openWindow() {
    window.open('default.aspx', null, 'height=200, width=400, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide the address bar, that's a thing the browsers don't let you turn off anymore.

Preventing scrolling is probably best handled via CSS inside whatever you're opening. Something like the following in a style block

```
body {overflow: hidden}
```

should stop the scrollbar appearing.